# No declaration found for element 'x:books'

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-namespaces, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I have an xml and an xsd. Both in the same directory. I am trying to validate it using xmlcopyeditor but it returns the following error.

```
Error at line 2, column 63: No declaration found for element "x:books"
```

Here is the xml.

file:books.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<x:books xmlns:x="urn:books" x:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="books.xsd">
   <book id="bk001">
      <author>Writer</author>
      <title>The First Book</title>
      <genre>Fiction</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <pub_date>2000-10-01</pub_date>
      <review>An amazing story of nothing.</review>
   </book>

   <book id="bk002">
      <author>Poet</author>
      <title>The Poet's First Poem</title>
      <genre>Poem</genre>
      <price>24.95</price>
      <review>Least poetic poems.</review>
   </book>
</x:books>
```

here is the xsd

file:books.xsd

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            targetNamespace="urn:books"
            xmlns:bks="urn:books">

  <xsd:element name="books" type="bks:BooksForm"/>

  <xsd:complexType name="BooksForm">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="book" 
                  type="bks:BookForm" 
                  minOccurs="0" 
                  maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>

  <xsd:complexType name="BookForm">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="author"   type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="title"    type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="genre"    type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="price"    type="xsd:float" />
      <xsd:element name="pub_date" type="xsd:date" />
      <xsd:element name="review"   type="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:attribute name="id"   type="xsd:string"/>
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

I found some similar question like [No declaration found for element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34818957/no-declaration-found-for-element) and [No declaration found for element ' '](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70712394/no-declaration-found-for-element) but I have not been able to fix it. I don't understand what's wrong I should be referencing the xsd correctly like that.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues in your XML and XSD, including:

1. Use `schemaLocation`, not `noNamespaceSchemaLocation`, for namespaced XML.
   See [How to link XML to XSD using schemaLocation or noNamespaceSchemaLocation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35411871/290085)
2. Use `xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"`.
   See [xmlns, xmlns:xsi, xsi:schemaLocation, and targetNamespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34202967/290085)
3. Use `elementFormDefault` in your XSD.
   See [What does elementFormDefault do in XSD?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46758277/290085)

The XML and XSD below have all issues resolved.  The fixed XML is now valid against the fixed XSD.

### XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<books xmlns="urn:books"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="urn:books books.xsd">
   <book id="bk001">
      <author>Writer</author>
      <title>The First Book</title>
      <genre>Fiction</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <pub_date>2000-10-01</pub_date>
      <review>An amazing story of nothing.</review>
   </book>
   <book id="bk002">
      <author>Poet</author>
      <title>The Poet's First Poem</title>
      <genre>Poem</genre>
      <price>24.95</price>
      <review>Least poetic poems.</review>
   </book>
</books>
```

### XSD

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            targetNamespace="urn:books"
            xmlns:bks="urn:books"
            elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xsd:element name="books" type="bks:BooksForm"/>
  <xsd:complexType name="BooksForm">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="book" 
                   type="bks:BookForm" 
                   minOccurs="0" 
                   maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:complexType name="BookForm">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="author"   type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="title"    type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="genre"    type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="price"    type="xsd:float" />
      <xsd:element name="pub_date" type="xsd:date" />
      <xsd:element name="review"   type="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:attribute name="id"   type="xsd:string"/>
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```